# Print Version CSS for CommonSpot

Tags: coldfusion, commonspot

Hey can any one tell me about how to link print version CSS?? I have created a head and linked the head file as

```
< link media="print" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
href="#request.subsiteCache[1].url#style/print.css">
```

but I'm unable to get the exact style version for the print as I have mentioned in print.css

Do I need to do anything more apart from this?

I'm using commonspot.

I wrapped it in cfoutput tags

Comment: Could you provide an example of the rendered head please?  Also is it in as `<link ...` or `< link .....`, as your example currently has a space between the `<` and `link` - if this is as it is in your source then that is incorrect

Comment: Check the full path in "view source" and paste it into the browser and pull up the CSS - verify it is what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you wrap your link tag around cfoutput?

```
<cfoutput>
    <link media="print" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#request.subsiteCache[1].url#style/print.css">
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: try dumping this variable "#request.subsiteCache[1].url#" outside the link tag and test what it is returning, and verify the path is right

Comment: hey i got that, the print version css is working when I have written this code in template file
<cfif request.renderforprint><cfelse>
<cfoutput>
<div id="page"><a href="#request.page.filename#?renderforprint=1"></a>
</cfoutput>
</cfif>

but still I'm not getting header part of my template in my print

do you have any idea about that?